# Gcc 4.2 version missing

Tags: macos, gcc, macports

on my new macbook pro with osx lion and XCode 4.1 I have some problems with gcc.

In `/usr/bin` I cannot find `gcc-4.2`

I only have the following versions:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
llvm-gcc
llvm-gcc-4.2
```

As a result when I try to select gcc42 by means of `port select --set gcc gcc42` it returns me the following error:
`Selecting 'gcc42' for 'gcc' failed: could not create new link "/opt/local/bin/gcc": target "/usr/bin/gcc-4.2" doesn't exist`

However `port select gcc` returns me the following versions:

```
apple-gcc42
gcc42
llvm-gcc42 (active)
mp-gcc44
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be a `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` with Xcode 4.1 installed.  However, with the recent Xcode 4.2 update, Apple has finally removed their modified standard `gcc-4.2`.  What remains is either `llvm-gcc42` (also symlinked to `gcc`) and `clang`, the newer non-gcc C compiler.  Apple is making the transition to `clang`; the first step is using the hybrid `llvm-gcc42`.  There have been some reported problems using either of the new compilers.  You should be using this time to figure out if you have problems with them and, if so, fix your code and report bugs to Apple.  In the meantime, if you absolutely have to have the old gcc-4.2, it is possible to build one similar to the previous Apple-modified one via MacPorts:

```
port install apple-gcc42
```

but you'll be swimming against the tide.

Comment: Thanks! I already installed gcc44 from macport and I can select it through `sudo port select -set gcc mp-gcc44`. However I cannot find it in `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: Ok, I found it in `/opt/loca/bin/` Actually the problem is that the software I'm compiling look for `/usr/bin/gcc42`  `IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM} MATCHES "Darwin-11.*")`

Comment: MacPorts never installs anything to `/usr/bin`; that is managed exclusively by Apple as part of OS X.  Is it possible to override the compiler selection with a CC environment variable or some such?

Answer (score 7):

I could manage to solve this issue in Mountain Lion with a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Hope this help someone

Answer (score 5):

With Xcode 4.3, you need to install the Command Line Tools separately. XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads, Click the Components button, and then click Install next to the "Command Line Tools" option.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

I fixed it by doing a symlink.

Like this :

```
cd /usr/bin
```

then :

```
sudo ln -s llvm-gcc-4.2 gcc-4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider compiling a newer GCC (e.g. 4.6.2) from its source [code](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Apple does not care much any more about GCC, but GCC has made significant progress since 4.2

And you probably could use your `llvm-gcc42` as a GCC compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I tampered with the innards of the makefile and found out that one invoked option provided an argument too many; replaced the variable with the actual result of the function called on my machine (removing the excess argument) and did run `make` again it worked.

Comment: What option? Care to show what changes you performed to the makefile?